# Android unreliable behavior of mediaplayer class

Tags: android

I have coded a simple app with a sound on button klick. On the emulator there indeed is a error: "**34 mp3extractor unable to resync. signalling end of stream**" 
But the sound has happened. I could hear it.

The problem is, **on some real devices the sound doesn't work first or second try after installing**. On a lot of devices the sound happens only from the second or third try.

That behavior is very unreliable and inconsistent.

Does anybody knows that problem? Thank you for your answers. 
This is my code:

Button.OnClickListener Button_Auswertung_OnClickListener =
           new Button.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {           

        MediaPlayer mepl = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this,  R.raw.sound);  
        mepl.start();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "klicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             

      }
```

};

Comment: You should not blindly edit the answer post. try commenting in comment section.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad, accept the answer when you get a moment I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recreate the `MediaPlayer` every time your onclick handler is called.

It would be better to create on that belongs to your activity or fragment and then call start() from the the onclick handler.

If the sound is going to be played a lot then a `SoundPool` might be a better idea.

Also you don't appear to be releasing your `MediaPlayer`, since you are creating a bunch of new ones this can result in exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Make your media player outside your on click:

```
 MediaPlayer mepl = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this,  R.raw.sound);  

 Button.OnClickListener Button_Auswertung_OnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {         

        public void onClick(View v) {           
             // just call start
             mepl.start();
             // also dont use app context for toasts
             Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "klicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             

        }
 };
```

You will want to check out the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for MEdiaPlayer, especially the state diagram.  It will help you understand how to use properly without error.

Hope this helps.